# html line break on narrow screen only

Tags: html, ios, screen

I want to put something into my html that forces a line break if the screen is below a certain width.  This is for iOS.  Can I do that?

Or, even better, is there a way to do some kind of if/else/endif that triggers off of screen width?  Something like this:

```
if screen width < 600 pixels
   some html
else
   some other html
endif
```

If it matters, which I'm hoping it won't, this is for an iOS device, at least initially.

EDIT: Here is an example:

```
<body>
    In spherical coordinates, given a vector field
    <math>
        <mn class="boldMath">F&#x2006;</mn>
        <mn>(</mn>
        <mi>r</mi>
        <mn>, </mn>
        <mi>&theta;</mi>
        <mn>, </mn>
        <mi>&phi;</mi>
        <mn>)</mn>
    </math>, the curl is<br>
    <math>
        <mrow>
            <mn mathvariant="bold">&nabla;</mn>
            <mn>&nbsp;&times;&nbsp;</mn>
            <mi mathvariant="bold">F</mi>
            <mn>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</mn>
        </mrow>
    </math>  <!-- I need a line break here on the phone, but not on the pad.  On the iPad, I would be delighted to have the above included in the mtable below.>
    <div class="center">
        <math>
            <mtable>
                                  <!-- long mtable here -->
            </mtable>
        </math>
    </div>
</body>
```

Output is good on the iPhone, not so much on the iPad.  See the bottom portion of each screen shot:

[image: iphone shot]
[image]

Comment: Forces a line break **where**? Is it really about **a** line break? Please show an example, with essential HTML and CSS code, and tell what should actually happen. There is surely no such conditionality in HTML, but in CSS, you can use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the containing element less wide it will automatically break the line.

Or if you like to have more control you could use a CSS media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #someelement { display: none; }
    #someotherelement { display: block; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get screen width by using this code:

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

opposite logic to @Jonas

```
#someelement br {  
    /* ignore <br> on large screen: */
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {  
    /* force <br> on narrow screen: */
    #someelement br { display: block; }
}
```